# Intermittently unable to getUser(), resulting in multiple calls to getLoginURL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The idea is that if a `user_id` exists, redirect the user to https://www.example.com/XYZ/. If not, call `getLoginUrl` to get the `user_id` first. The problem is that I cannot get any `user_id`. Thus, the script keeps going to `getLoginUrl` which results in a CSRF error occurring (I get multiple State values). The problem is very random though.

Any ideas?

```
require_once('../src/facebook.php');
require_once ('../src/fbconfig.php');

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if (!$user_id) {
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
      'scope'         => 'publish_stream, user_likes')
    );
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>top.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/XYZ/'</script>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Have you check if the **appId** and **secret** values are the one from the app?.  I would suggest you to print everything from **getSignedRequest()** and see what is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print_r($user_id);
```

after you set $user_id and keep trying until you find one of those "random" cases and observe what it is returning.  You'll then need to add additional conditions to your if/then statement to handle the unexpected return, or perhaps perform a retry [with limit of course to prevent race condition].

Also depending on server and magic quotes setting, you may want to change your redirect code in the first case to the following:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>";
```

I doubt that has anything to do with it or you'd see that in the URL, but hard to tell what's happening with your app and "random" are always a pain.  Try and figure out what IS returning during those "random" cases and that should tell you how to handle it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: I added magic quotes setting you suggested, however i didn't work. The result printed from $user_id is always "0" while the State value keep changing.

Comment: this sounds like an issue with the facebook class then if always 0.  check credentials perhaps or search on that library to see if others with same issue.